# Docker multi-stage build not running all stages

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I am trying to build an image from this Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:14-slim-buster AS builder
WORKDIR application
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} application.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract

FROM openjdk:14-slim-buster
WORKDIR application
COPY --from=builder application/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/resources/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/application/ ./
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

The problem is it never reaches the second stage.  I can see the total steps in the counter when the image is being built, but it just stops and executes this as a new container which is running the actual application

`RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract`

Comment: Do you have `application` directory in the image? if not you should create it by adding this `RUN mkdir /application` just before `WORKDIR`

Comment: Yes it is there, no matter what i do it is executing this line and starts a container right away.


Step 5/12 : RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract
 ---> Running in a6be56cbbd96

Comment: Please show the full command being run and output. Also, what `docker version`?

Comment: So far i have tried ```docker build . -t testcontainer --no-cache``` but when i use it with --target builder it just create the image for that part i can see only those steps in the counter. i tried to name other step as [production] ```docker build . -t testcontainer --no-cache --target production``` but it just starts from the beginning and again get caught at RUN.

Comment: i am using docker desktop 2.2.0.5 stable, with engine : 19.03.8

Comment: output looks like this : Step 5/12 : RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract ---> Running in a6be56cbbd96 after this it just ran the jar

Comment: i am wondering if it has something to do with ```java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract ```

Comment: What does that command do?  A `RUN` instruction will run the command it names, and not move on until it finishes.  So if that "extract" step isn't finishing for whatever reason, it will block things from moving on.

Comment: Are you using `buildkit`? That will skip stages not used by `--target` by default, at least in more recent versions of docker. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63638918/5443120)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, it was happening because of the Spring Boot version which was not ready to handle multistage builds, but after upgrading the service to 2.3.x i can build.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of the Jar file not in supported form.
That's why jarmode can't process it.
Jarmode is a special system used to extracting Layered Jars.

You can check out: https://spring.io/blog/2020/01/27/creating-docker-images-with-spring-boot-2-3-0-m1 for detail info.