# Dockerfile - Which option to use the target?

Tags: docker, cypress

I have dockerfile

```
FROM cypress/base:12.1.0 as hlg 
RUN mkdir /app WORKDIR /app COPY . /app 
RUN npm install  
RUN $(npm bin)/cypress verify 
RUN ["npm", "run", "cy:runhlg"]

FROM cypress/base:12.1.0 as tst 
RUN mkdir /app WORKDIR /app COPY . /app 
RUN npm install  
RUN $(npm bin)/cypress verify 
RUN ["npm", "run", "cy:runtst"]
```

then I build it

```
docker build -t cypress --target tst .
```

But I need to run only one per run, when I run with the target "tst" it ends up running both.

I tried to do it with "if", but without success too

```
RUN if [ "$arg" = "hlg" ] ; then echo ["npm", "run", "cy:runhlg"] ; else echo ["npm", "run", "cy:runhlg"]; fi
docker build -t cypress --build-arg hlg .
```

Can I do it the other way?

Comment: You can split this into two separate Dockerfiles, or override the command when you run the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic build engine in docker will process a multi-stage build sequentially until completing the target stage, or the final stage is no target is specified. So the first stage would always be built.

If you switch to buildkit, it processes the Dockerfile into a dependency graph and skips unused stages. You can enable buildkit in your current shell with:

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
```

And you can make buildkit the default for all builds in the docker engine by enabling a feature flag in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` (the `daemon.json` can also be set in the desktop versions of docker under one of the preferences menus):

```
{
  "features": {"buildkit": true }
}
```

To process the `daemon.json` file, reload the docker engine, e.g. `systemctl reload docker`.

Comment: This error has occurred. Thank you for your help ////
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount717586437/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

Comment: Are you running your build in the directory with the Dockerfile?

Comment: Yes.
[+] Building 1.4s (2/2) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile  1.2s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2B  0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                         0.9s 
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                          0.0s 
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount717586437/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

Comment: The error message is indicating otherwise. Check the spelling, case sensitive (capital D), and ensure there's no extension on the file.